# Startup crash iOS App on certain devices

Tags: ios, swift

I have a lesson-planning app for music teachers ([CS Music Teacher](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/creative-sequence-music-teacher/id994759206?ls=1&mt=8)) that was recently released. For most users it's working fine, but for 3 users, the app quits immediately on launch.

Here are the steps:

1. User opens app (just fine), signs up for service (just fine), logs in (just fine).
2. User creates first lesson (just fine).
3. User leaves, opens app to continue working, and it crashes immediately after splash screen.

Deleting and reinstalling app does not solve the problem. For some strange reason, deleting the *lesson* solves the problem, but it repeats when they make a new lesson.

Yet there's nothing different about the lessons. In fact, one user can use the app fine on his iPad, but the crash happens on his iPhone. Another user has crashes on an iPad mini.

I don't have access to the crash data from the users :(

So here are my guesses. If you think one of these is the right area to look, I'll try to figure out what code to add:

- Core Data is corrupted: This often causes this kind of immediate crash. But in the past, I thought a full delete/reinstall would clear this?
- Every lesson is synced with a server, and there is a problem when the app tries to sync/download on startup. But again, I have no idea why this would be different for a few devices.

Comment: Without crash logs, it will be difficult for us to help you :/

Comment: I realize that. Unfortunately, they're not showing up in the itunesconnect crash logs, and I didn't know about 3rd party crash log collection until after the fact. I guess I'll have to install a crash collection program into the app, submit an update, and wait for people to crash again. Unless there's a way for users to send me crash logs?

Comment: Try logging in using their account to ensure it's not specific to their data. Get versions and devices to see if it's related to specific device or version. If those check out, I'm guessing a threading issue, which will crash on some systems and not others, depending on some race condition.

Comment: Thanks, Marcus. I can log into their accounts and it works fine via my devices and simulator.

Comment: Threading - is it possible to elaborate? What are race conditions? Thanks.